# Changes via GUI thread are not reflected in workerscript

Tags: qt, qml

In the code below, listmodel is shared between the threads and a timer is set to update the model's value, these changes should be reflected(desired behavior) in workerscript ([docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-listmodel.html#using-threaded-list-models-with-workerscript)). But in workerscript, it is always the initial value as it does not know data has changed.

// main file

```
    Window {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 150
    height: 200
    title: qsTr("Hello Testing")

    DataModel {
        id: model
    }

    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            model.setProperty(0, 'datum', new Date().toLocaleString())
        }
    }

    WorkerScript {
        id: bgScript
        source: "script.js"

    }

    Timer {
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            bgScript.sendMessage({'model': model})
        }
    }

    Text {
        id: datum
        text: qsTr(model.get(0).datum)
    }

}
```

// workerscript

```
WorkerScript.onMessage = function (arg) {
    console.log(arg.model.get(0).datum)   // value is "Date Time" on every call
}
```

// model

```
ListModel {

    ListElement {
        datum: "Date Time"
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You copied your model into a JS object and passed that object into a JS function. You will never receive notification of updates to an object like that from within the JS function. Bindings only work on QML properties, not JS values.

But even if that did work in general, it still wouldn't work within a `WorkerScript`. According to the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-workerscript.html#restrictions), a WorkerScript js file doesn't have access to properties from the calling QML.

> Since the WorkerScript.onMessage() function is run in a separate
> thread, the JavaScript file is evaluated in a context separate from
> the main QML engine. This means that unlike an ordinary JavaScript
> file that is imported into QML, the script.mjs in the above example
> cannot access the properties, methods or other attributes of the QML
> item, nor can it access any context properties set on the QML object
> through QQmlContext.

Comment: Thanks for support.  Even if it is being copied, program has to transfer a new copy of model on every trigger[timer].

Comment: Secondly, docs says **ListModel can be used together with WorkerScript access a list model from multiple threads**

Comment: Yeah, I understand your point. Are you able to print your value right after you call `setProperty`?

Comment: I think workerscript takes over the model and syncs the changes to GUI thread and it does not work the other way around.